# Three statements within if

Tags: arduino

I'm currently working on a small Arduino project, and I'm kinda stuck. Here's my code so far:

```
#include "_init.h"

void setup() {
  ds_init();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(LIGHT_SENSOR_PIN));

  int rol1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int rol2[] = {3, 5, 1, 2, 4};
  int rol3[] = {5, 1, 4, 3, 2};

  int rol1Mid = random(0, 5);
  int rol1Bov = rol1Mid + 1;
  int rol1Ond = rol1Mid - 1;

  if (rol1Bov == 5){
    rol1Bov = 0;
  }

  if (rol1Ond == -1){
    rol1Ond = 4;
  }

  int rol2Mid = random(0, 5);
  int rol2Bov = rol2Mid + 1;
  int rol2Ond = rol2Mid - 1;

  if (rol2Bov == 5){
    rol2Bov = 0;
  }

  if (rol2Ond == -1){
    rol2Ond = 4;
  }

  int rol3Mid = random(0, 5);
  int rol3Bov = rol3Mid + 1;
  int rol3Ond = rol3Mid - 1;

  if (rol3Bov == 5){
    rol3Bov = 0;
  }

  if (rol3Ond == -1){
    rol3Ond = 4;
  }  

  Serial.println(rol1[rol1Bov]);
  Serial.println(rol1[rol1Mid]);
  Serial.println(rol1[rol1Ond]);

  Serial.println("----");

  Serial.println(rol2[rol2Bov]);
  Serial.println(rol2[rol2Mid]);
  Serial.println(rol2[rol2Ond]);

  Serial.println("----");

  Serial.println(rol3[rol3Bov]);
  Serial.println(rol3[rol3Mid]);
  Serial.println(rol3[rol3Ond]);

  if(rol1[rol1Mid] && rol2[rol2Mid] == rol3[rol3Mid]){
    Serial.println("Yaay!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Jammer, probeer het nogmaals.");
  }
  /*
  if(rol1[positieBov] && rol2[positieBov] == rol3[positieBov]){
    Serial.println("Yaay!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Jammer, probeer het nogmaals.");
  }

  if(rol1[positieOnd] && rol2[positieOnd] == rol3[positieOnd]){
    Serial.println("Yaay!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Jammer, probeer het nogmaals.");
  }
  */
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 

}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a slot machine. There's probably tons of things wrong with my code, but for the time being, I'm stuck on the if statement that checks if the user won or not.

I know I shouldnt be coding in the setup() part of Arduino, but as soon as this all works, I'm going to put it in a function in the loop(), where I will use my dangershield's buttons to operate the three roll's separately.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, managed to fix it... I feel silly now

```
if(rol1[rol1Mid] == rol2[rol2Mid] && rol2[rol2Mid] == rol3[rol3Mid])
```